# Values are incorrect while using String.Format

Tags: c#, .net, string

I need to convert a decimal value into something like

> 0.3 = USDC000000000030

The code i wrote is as below.

```
   transactionAmount = String.Format("USDC{0}", ((int)(amount*100)).ToString("D12"));
```

However, it is working for some values perfectly like the example given above. For other some values it is conversion is wrong for example

> 0.9 = USDC000000000089
>
> 1 = USDC000000000099
>
> 1.1 USDC000000000109

Any idea why is it happening so?

Thanks in advance

Comment: looks like floating-point error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably using `double`, which for financial values is a huge mistake.

Use `decimal` instead, and wash your troubles away.

To wit:

```
decimal amount = 0.3m;
string s = String.Format("USDC{0:000000000000}", 100 * amount);
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Output:

```
USDC000000000030
```

Note that the language specification states:

> The decimal type is a 128-bit data type suitable for financial and monetary calculations.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
String.Format("USDC{0:D12}", (int)(Convert.ToDecimal(amount) * 100));
```

Tested with the following:

- 0.90 = USDC000000000090
- 1.00 = USDC000000000100
- 0.89 = USDC000000000089
- 0.84 = USDC000000000084
- 1.10 = USDC000000000110

Comment: What should it be in that case? `USDC00000000090`?

Comment: i am still getting 0.9 =USDC000000000089. when tried the code you gave. thank you

Comment: What is the data type you're using for `amount`. I've edited my answer to include a conversion to decimal.

Comment: Just tested, and this happens when `amount` is a float. The addition of `Convert.ToDecimal` resolves the issue though.

Comment: @logeeks: Okay, that makes sense. Conversion to decimal will remedy the issue.